# Is there any way to apply tooltip only on paticular element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a doubletable in Jquery, where i need to show tooltip on one element.I have a button parallel to the element to move to another table as shown in screen. If i apply tooltip on element it is applied for button also, which results in odd behaviour especially in IE8.Please let me know how can i apply tooltip only on particular element.

Code:

```
var details = popup_skill_modify_tableLessons.getTableSelected().fnGetData(node, 4);
$(node).attr('title', details).tooltip();
```

Please let me know the solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Found answer for my requirement.
- Applied tooltip only for the desired column of the row(node).

  $(node.childNodes[desired child index]).attr('title', details).tooltip();

Answer (score 0):

Add a new class `myTooltip` And try the below code

```
$(".myTooltip").tooltip({
        tooltipClass:"ui-tooltip1"
    });
```